# PubNub keeps receiving one message over and over

Tags: pubnub

Just started with PubNub, and seems that I fail to understand even the simplest possible scenario. I created the following test page:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.15.1.js"></script>
<script>
const pubnub = new PubNub({
  publishKey : '<guid>',
  subscribeKey : '<one more guid>'
});
pubnub.subscribe({channels: ['3']});
pubnub.addListener({
  message: v => {
    console.log("on message", v);
  },
});
function onClick() {
  pubnub.publish({channel: '3', message: 'foo'});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="onClick()">start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Opening it with latest Chrome and clicking "start" button will result in test message being received endlessly over and over. I was under impression that after single client receives a message from a bus, this client will not receive it again. why such behaviour? I understand that I can read `all` the docs and most probably answer is somewhere deep inside, but tutorial + quickstart gives no clues, and rest of docs are quite huge.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your example code works perfectly for me.  The message published is received one time on the channel "3".  One way to validate this is to simultaneously have the PubNub Console open (https://www.pubnub.com/docs/console).  Make sure you enter your Publish and Subscribe keys into the console, along with the channel "3".  After clicking the "Subscribe" button in the PubNub Console, you should see your test message "foo" appearing once in the "messages" section at the bottom each time you click the "start" button on your test page.

Comment: I got the same result as Todd - single message. You are using MS Edge (never tried it) so can you try on Chrome and Firebox and let us know if you get the same or different results on those?

Comment: I'm using latest Chrome. It's displayed on my screenshot. Why Edge? @CraigConover

Comment: Oh, nm, I saw *edge* in your path and for some reason assumed Edge browser. So we are not sure what is going on here. There must be some other outside actor causing this to happen as it is not expected and we are unable to reproduce it. I see that you submitted to PN support. Can you attached the full source file in that ticket even if you are certain it is 100% the same as above? Many thanks!

Comment: For history: all info, debug logs etc alongside with video example was sent.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you're using the latest SDK-JS V4 (perfect starting point)

- Your code works!

I would like to point you to a bit of a diff way to init PubNub and few functionalities.

(which are available in their docs)

Please look at the attached link to view my [PubNub demo](https://pastebin.com/0mXAnuGA)

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
       console.log('init PubNub.');    
       pubnub = new PubNub({
         publishKey: 'demo',
         subscribeKey: 'demo',
         uuid: 'myDemo'
       })

       console.log("addListener..");
       pubnub.addListener({
         status: function(statusEvent) {
           if (statusEvent.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
             console.log("PNConnectedCategory..");
             publishSampleMessage();
           }
         },
         message: function(message) {
           console.log("New Message!!", message.message);          
         },
         presence: function(presenceEvent) {
           //handle presence
         }
       })

       console.log("Subscribing..");
       pubnub.subscribe({
         channels: ['myDemo']
       });

       function publishSampleMessage() {
         console.log("Since we're publishing on subscribe connectEvent, we're sure we'll receive the following publish.");
         var publishConfig = {
           channel: "myDemo",
           message: "I'm here, I'm alive!!"
         }
         pubnub.publish(publishConfig, function(status, response) {
           console.log(status, response);
         })
       }

     function onClick() {
       publishSampleMessage();
     }

  </script>
```